# Why can't my JavaFX project import the libraries even though I can see them?

Tags: java, javafx, intellij-14

This is a git project I am working on with my student team. I was using community Intellij and my project was working fine. I upgrade to ultimate edition and now I cannot get my project to build because it cannot find the JavaFX libraries that I can see in the project structure.
I have the JavaFX plugin enabled. On the left of the following screenshot I can see the JavaFX dependencies.

[image: what I see]

Comment: that safe mode warning in the blue box might have something to do with it. Try selecting trust project

Comment: Create a new JavaFX project using the [wizard](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html).  If that works copy your source into the new project.  You won’t need to add JavaFX dependencies as the Idea build integration will do that for you.  You will just to add dependencies for the non JavaFX libraries you are using like hikari by adding them to the Maven project and module-info.java if you use one, and resynching the Maven project with your idea project.

Comment: Your code should not be using com.sun classes, they are not public API and might not continue to work.

Comment: Also your project structure is really weird, which makes it fragile, hard to maintain and hard for others to understand. Stuck to the Maven standard directory layout (even if you unadvisedly end up not using Maven or gradle). Run a Google search for the layout definition.

Comment: You have three different versions of controlsfx defined in your project.  Don’t do that, it is a recipe for disaster, instead just let the wizard choose a version for you which it puts in the generated Maven project and idea works out the lib path from that without any manual setup.  You probably have other problems but those were some I noticed from your screenshot.  Basically, don’t try to fix your broken project.  Start from a new project that works and gradually copy stuff over testing at each small step until you have a complete working system built with a tool like Maven.

Comment: I got rid of safe mode warning and clicked trust project but it did not fix anything.

Comment: I also did not set up any of the dependencies it was someone else in the project. I just checked the dependencies listings and mine are the same as my partners but I get errors.

Comment: That is the whole point of my recommendation set, to refactor the project so that the build is not fragile and won’t break across developers.  If you define everything in Maven, all major Java IDEs will be able to import the project without doing IDE and project specific setup hacks.  It doesn’t matter who made it or that it happens to run OK in somebodies IDE today, the fact is that it is a fragile, non-portable project definition which is causing problems, you can choose to fix it or not.

Comment: @jewelsea I see. Could you point me in the right direction to doing that then? Sorry i'm still pretty new at setting up these kinds of projects. So I need to move all dependencies to Maven?

Comment: I already provided detailed instructions, there is not much  more I can do in this forum.  I know it is difficult, otherwise it would have been done the better way from the start.  This has been an industry wide issue since forever.  It has only been a situation which has improved in recent years due to the gradual wide spread acceptance of convention over configuration and the widespread use of tools like Maven and Gradle which adopt that via the Maven standard directory project. Conversion is difficult, benefits are great.

Comment: Pick a tool (Maven or Gradle), I suggest Maven, search for high quality tutorials on the tool and how it integrates with your chosen IDE, learn it and follow my advice from comments  You don’t have to do that to solve your issue, but it is what I advise.